# How AWS personalize selects interactions when number of interactions is more than 500M?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

According to the docs, the Maximum number of interactions that are considered by a model during training is 500M. What if I have more than 500M records in my interactions dataset? How does Amazon select 500M interactions among those to train a model? Does it consider the latest 500M interactions?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent 500M interactions are used for training based on the TIMESTAMP column in the interactions dataset. This limit is also adjustable.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/limits.html